# Using the default contact picker photo in my app

Tags: android, contacts

In my app I have a ListView of contacts with basic information (name, phone number) as well as the contact image, very similar to the default Android contact picker.  If the contact has no image, it displays the app icon in its place.  However, I would like to use the default silhouette image that the contact picker uses instead.  My question is how can I access this image and use it in my app?  Here is the section of my code that loads the contact image:

```
Contact c = new Contact();

    final String[] projection = new String[] {
        Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, // the name of the contact
        Contacts.PHOTO_ID // the ID of the column in the data table for the image
    };


    final Cursor contact = getContentResolver().query(
        Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
        projection,
        Contacts._ID + "=?", // filter entries on the basis of the contact id
        new String[] {String.valueOf(contactId)}, // the parameter which the contact id column is compared to
        null
    );

    if(contact.moveToFirst()) {
        final String name = contact.getString(
                contact.getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        final String photoId = contact.getString(
                contact.getColumnIndex(Contacts.PHOTO_ID));

        // Get photo data for this contact
        if(photoId != null) {
            final Cursor photo = managedQuery(
                Data.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] {Photo.PHOTO}, // column for the photo blob
                Data._ID + "=?", // select row by id
                new String[] {photoId}, // filter by photoId
                null
            );

            // Convert photo blob to a bitmap
            if(photo.moveToFirst()) {
                byte[] photoBlob = photo.getBlob(
                        photo.getColumnIndex(Photo.PHOTO));
                final Bitmap photoBitmap = 
                    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photoBlob, 0, photoBlob.length);

                c.setPhoto(photoBitmap);
            }


        }



        c.setName(name);
```

Here is the code in my ContactAdapter class which associates the ImageView with the contacts photo:

```
ImageView photo = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.contact_photo);

if(photo != null) {
            if(c.hasPhoto()) photo.setImageBitmap(c.getPhoto());
            else photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.app_icon);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually 3 different images that are used in Android.  You can find them in the drawable folder of the resources that come with the emulator, or you can download them from here:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! The image I was looking for was the Honeycomb version, its just a silhouette of a person.  I found it in the android-11 resources folder.

Comment: It would be SO nice if Google would expose the images directly from the SDK, instead of us needing to include them locally, ... that way our apps would always be up to date with the current look.

Comment: @eidylon While that would be nice, that is precisely why Google is not doing it (and that is a Good Thing). It's because in the future, they could change the default assets to something different that doesn't fit the appearance of your app at all, and mess up your well crafted design.

Comment: That makes sense, if you are rolling your own themes for your app. But if you're using built in themes (such as Holo or DeviceDefault), and attempting to keep your app looking as consistent as possible with Google's design guidelines by using the available resources when possible, then this would ensure that apps maintain Google's design aesthetic as much as possible. If you are rolling your own theme and don't want to be messed up by core asset changes, then you just roll your own assets to go with your own theme.